# Framer motion whileInView activating before component is in viewport

Tags: reactjs, frontend, css-animations, framer-motion, chakra-ui

I'm trying to make a simple animation with Framer Motion where a component floats in and turns opaque from the left. This component is directly below the hero section, but does not appear in the viewport when at the top of the page(the hero section is the entire viewport height). The component is in a separate div than the hero section. Note that I am using Chakra UI if that has anything to do with this. I am wrapping it in a motion.div element as shown below:

```
<motion.div     
        initial={{ x: -400, opacity: 0}}
        whileInView={{ x: 0, opacity: 1}}
        transition={{ duration: 3 }}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
        >
        <Box alignContent='right' id='about'>
            <Flex>
                <Spacer />
                    <VStack>
                        <Heading>Some heading</Heading>
                        <Text>
                            Some Text
                        </Text>
                    </VStack>
                <Spacer />
            </Flex>
        </Box>
    </motion.div>
```

The animation starts before the component is in the viewport. I know the animation is working, because when I scroll quickly after the page loads, I see it halfway finished. However, if I leave it for a few seconds and then scroll down, the animation is already complete.

I am new to Framer motion and just followed the examples. Please let me know if you see my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to use "useInView" hook.
you can define a ref for your element and use that ref as an argument for the hook so It will observe that element.

[you can see the examples from here](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-in-view/)

Answer (score 1):

In the viewport prop, add `amount: 0.5` as a property. This results in the `whileInView` variant only being shown when at least 50% of the element is in view.

The default is 0, which means when any of the element is in view, and that typically will result in the animation starting when most of the element is not yet in view!

Link to the viewport prop docs: https://www.framer.com/motion/scroll-animations/###amount

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to add a 'threshold: 0.5'.

I am having the opposite problem,  that when my threshold is above 0.1 the animation does not begin until after I have left the viewport

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no option for threshhold in framer motion